# Could we use Azure Active Directory(AAD) B2B and B2C in single application??? B2B for Microsoft Intune access and B2C for user login/signup

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, intune, azure-ad-b2b

I have an requirement to implement both Azure B2C and B2B in a single application where B2C is used to login/signup, after user's login/signup the B2B is used to get Microsoft Intune Access??? is that possible to implement this flow?? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add multiple providers to most applications, for example if you use API's and azure functions or webapps etc, this can done either with EasyAuth or in your own code.

In simple terms you end up adding AAD as one provider and B2C as a second provider, meaning that your application will trust tokens from both services and then you go from there.